# A tool that logs inbound links to a specified list of sites?

Tags: seo, competitors

I'm doing some competitor analysis for one of our sites and working with a site based in an unfamiliar industry, I'm basically analysing the backlinks to our competitors. What would be useful is a tool that would take a list of sites and then return a list of backlinks to all of them - with anything else like pagerank (and other useful stats) of backlinking pages.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/), a 'search engine for links', is useful for discovering backlinks. It lists total backlinks, linking root domains, top pages and much more, and attempts to score page and domain authority based on their own interpretation of PageRank scoring. You can compare up to five sites by clicking the 'compare pages' button on the homepage.

SEOBook also has a [long list of free competitive research tools](http://tools.seobook.com/competitive-research-tools/) that may prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo Site Explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/) will allow you to find of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mixrank, Ahrefs and Open site explorer are the tools that can be used for competitor analysis. You'll be able to find even PPC campaigns of your competitor using mixrank.

One thing you'll notice here is that links registered by Yahoo explorer and Google webmaster tools differ in numbers.